# Need a lightweight Screencasting Software

Tags: video, software-rec, screencasts, video-capture

I need a lightweight screencasting software recommendation, something that wouldn't slow the computer down too much.

I've previously tried to use one software for recording while I played a video game, but everything became a lot slower as a result.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this post from [Lifehacker.com](http://lifehacker.com):

> [Five Best Screencasting Tools](http://lifehacker.com/5410229/five-best-screencasting-tools).

The three free ones (links and descriptions in link above):

- Jing
- CamStudio
- Screentoaster

Comment: Which one is the fastest and least resource hungry?

Comment: Camstudio is by far the best, I experienced almost no difference whatsoever while it was recording. Brilliant!